# Cypress testing and waiting for axios requests

Tags: reactjs, automated-tests, cypress

Can anyone explain how or why my test isn't waiting for my data from an axios request before moving on? I'm completely new to this but have most simple stuff worked out but can't seem to navigate the docs to find where i'm going wrong.
Here's the relevant info..

```
cy.get('.day').eq(4).click() //Change the day
cy.route('/api/practice/available-slots').as('apiCheck') //Get available slots for that day
cy.wait('@apiCheck') //Wait for the days available slots to be returned
```

So you can see below I click the fourth day and my post URL is showing and getting data like it normally does but then my wait function throws that error. I like to think i'm close but as I said i'm new and not entirely sure what's going wrong. Thanks

[image]

For what it's worth here's the axios request:

```
axios
    .post(this.props.reqProto + this.props.reqHost + '/api/practice/available-slots', {
      startDate: this.state.appointmentSlotsDate,
    })
    .then((res) => {
          ....
     }
 })
```

Comment: [cy.route()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Arguments) "If no method is defined Cypress will match GET requests by default", but your xhr is 'POST' so add the method as first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Hiram,

That was one issue. Also the order of my code was incorrect. I need to allow cypress to anticipate the POST request instead of it trying to double back to it. This seems to work

```
cy.route({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/api/practice/available-slots',
}).as('apiCheck')

cy.get('.day').eq(4).click()
cy.wait('@apiCheck')
```